# VisualStudio2022 can't navigate from compile error to source

Tags: gcc, ide, visual-studio-2022

I'm using VisualStudio 2022 community to develop linux program. The cross-platform compile do works and compile outputs shows *Output* view well.
But when double click the error message, it can't jump to source code of error place.

How to fix it?

I use GCC 8.4 on Centos 8 OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason of my problem now.
Setting of "Remote build root" is incorrect in CMakeSettings.json.
This is the root dir of building on server, this path combine with the file path  from gcc error message should point to the correct source file